# Combobox dropdown list bug

Tags: javascript, extjs

I render ExtJS 6 combobox to some dom element and the problem is that when I expand this combobox and start to use mouse wheel, then this dropdown list does not position itself correctly. It looks like so:

BEFORE
[image]

AFTER
[image]

As you can see on the second screen the dropdown list is far away from the component.

Unfortunatelly, I can not provide some short reproducible example, because I use some third party window component, in which I try to render ExtJS components. But I still hope, that someone knows some possible combobox configs that can help to target this issue.

**EDIT**

This is a minimized example that reproduces the error:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Demo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../ext-6.2.2/build/classic/theme-triton/resources/theme-triton-all.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="../ext-6.2.2/build/ext-all.js"></script>    
<style>
    .uk-modal {
        z-index: 1304;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        overflow: auto !important;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
    .uk-open .uk-modal-dialog {
        height: 1000px;
        width: 600px;
        padding: 24px;
        display: block !important;
        position: relative;
        margin: 50px auto;            
        background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    }
</style>
</head>
<body style="margin:0; padding:0">
<div class="uk-modal uk-open">
    <div class="uk-modal-dialog">
        <div id="combobox"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
Ext.application({
    name : 'Demo',
    appFolder: '.',
    autoCreateViewport: false,
    launch: function(){
        var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
            data : [
                {"abbr":"AL", "name":"Alabama"},
                {"abbr":"AK", "name":"Alaska"},
                {"abbr":"AZ", "name":"Arizona"}
            ]
        });
        Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
            fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
            store: states,
            queryMode: 'local',
            displayField: 'name',
            valueField: 'abbr',
            renderTo: 'combobox'
        });
    }
});
</script>
</body>
```

That's it. Just pay attention to `.uk-open .uk-modal-dialog` `height` style, that should be large enough, so that you may use your mouse wheel to scroll down.

Comment: What I see in the DOM, is that this dropdown picker has absolute position and some top and left styles defined. And these top and left style properties do not change when I use mouse wheel.

Comment: It seems to be a styles problem, probably some style is messing around. If you cannot reproduce it in a simpler context I'd try to remove all possible styles to see if it starts working as it should. Also, if the combo as it is now existed without the problem and some change led to the problem, I'd try to see what styles changes were made.

Comment: Thanks, Diego! I will try to mimic all styles, although it will be a hard task.

Comment: Oh, fantastic! I was able to minimize the example. So, now this bug is completely reproducible. There is no JS code, just a little bit of CSS.

Comment: Please post the CSS that is causing the error

Comment: Please, have a look. I attached a complete example.

Comment: To see the bug, expand the dropdown list and use your mouse wheel to scroll down.

Comment: The page you posted has references to your local files. However what you should be saying is if removing the `style` tag you left there the problem stops. If it does try to norrow it down to which of those classes

Comment: These are not my local files, these are ExtJS library files - one with JS code and another one with its CSS code.

Comment: So, if you have ExtJS on your machine, you may just pay attention to CSS that I use. I do not use here any third party code.

Comment: I don't have ExtJS on my machine and the references you added are local to yours, not form any cdn. Have you tried removing that `style` tag?

Comment: I will create a fiddle in a minute

Comment: Here is a fiddle - https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1uov . Please, have a look

Comment: Indeed, if we remove style tag, it works. Because the whole problem is in these styles.

Comment: Is there any reason to set  `position: fixed;` on `.uk-modal`? Without it, it works perfectly

Comment: I'm not sure if it is necessary. I took it from the third library, that I use. I will try to override it. Thanks! BTW. You may create an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try just removing the `position: fixed;` for `.uk-modal` in your styles. At least in the simplified example it is not needed and it is causing the error.

Comment: It works, though I see that in production, when I override this position: fixed style, I get a completely broken layout.

Comment: I haven't seen any element regarding the combobox with the class `uk-modal` so I believe you should try to find which element is inheriting the `position: fixed` and override it just for it.